# SQLite Database is locked while insert query

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I'll share my helper class. I got Database is locked error while i am using SQLiteAddcustomer function. I found some solutions with "using" statements, but problem still continues. How can i solve this problem ?

```
public class SQLiteHelper
{
    String gDatabaseName = @"Data Source=RTM_Spark.sqlite;Version=3;";
    SQLiteConnection gConnection;
    SQLiteCommand gCommand;
    SQLiteDataReader gDataReader;
    SQLiteDataReader gDataReaderRoot;
    SQLiteDataReader gDataReaderDirectory;
    SQLiteDataReader gDataReaderCustomer;
    SQLiteDataReader gDataReaderDevice;

    public SQLiteHelper()
    {
        gDatabaseName = @"Data Source=RTM_Spark.sqlite;Version=3;";
    }

    public SQLiteHelper(String pDatabaseName)
    {
        gDatabaseName = String.Format("Data Source={0}", pDatabaseName);
    }

    public void SQLiteExecuteQuery(String pSQLCommand)
    {
        gCommand = new SQLiteCommand(gConnection);
        gCommand.CommandText = pSQLCommand;
        gCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public int SQLiteGetNodeID(String pSelectedNode)
    {
        int tSubID = 0;
        if (gConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT ID FROM tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeName='{0}'", pSelectedNode));
            gDataReader = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (gDataReader.Read())
            {
                tSubID = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReader["ID"]);
            }
        }
        return tSubID;
    }

    public int SQLiteGetNodeType(String pSelectedNode)
    {
        int tNodeType = 0;
        if (gConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT nodeType FROM tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeName='{0}'", pSelectedNode));
            gDataReader = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (gDataReader.Read())
            {
                tNodeType = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReader["nodeType"]);

            }
        }
        return tNodeType;
    }

    public void SQLiteAddCustomer(TreeNode pSelectedNode, String pCustomerName)
    {
        int tNodeType = 99;
        if (gConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT nodeType FROM tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeName='{0}'", pCustomerName));
            SQLiteDataReader tDataReader = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (tDataReader.Read())
            {
                tNodeType = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReader["nodeType"]);
            }
            if (tNodeType == 0 || tNodeType == 1 || tNodeType == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(pCustomerName + " already saved on your list.");
            }
            else
            {
                int tSelectedID = SQLiteGetNodeID(pSelectedNode.Text);
                int tSelectedNodeType = SQLiteGetNodeType(pSelectedNode.Text);
                if (tSelectedNodeType == 0)
                {
                    gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
                    this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO tblNodes (nodeName,nodeType,nodeSubID,isVisible) VALUES ('{0}',1,'{1}',1)", pCustomerName, tSelectedID));
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("You can add Customer under directory");
            }
        }

    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(String pSQLCommand)
    {
        gConnection = new SQLiteConnection(gDatabaseName);
        gConnection.Open();
        gCommand = new SQLiteCommand(gConnection);
        gCommand.CommandText = pSQLCommand;
        int rowsUpdated = gCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return rowsUpdated;

    }

    public void SQLiteOpenConnection()
    {
        gConnection = new SQLiteConnection(gDatabaseName);
        gConnection.Open();
    }

    public void SQLiteCloseConnection()
    {
        gConnection.Close();
    }

    public int SQLiteGetRootID()
    {
        int tRootID = 0;
        if (gConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT ID FROM tblNodes where nodeName='{0}'", "RTM Spark"));
            gDataReader = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (gDataReader.Read())
            {
                tRootID = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReader["ID"]);
            }
        }
        gConnection.Close();
        return tRootID;
    }

    public void UpdateTreeView(TreeView pTreeView) 
    {
        refreshDatabaseConnection();
        pTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeNode rootNode = pTreeView.Nodes.Add("RTM Spark");
        getDirectoryNameQuery();
        while (gDataReaderRoot.Read())
        {
            String tDirectoryName = gDataReaderRoot["nodeName"].ToString();
            TreeNode directoryNode = rootNode.Nodes.Add(tDirectoryName);
            rootNode.ExpandAll();
            getDirectoryIDQuery(tDirectoryName);
            while (gDataReaderDirectory.Read())
            {
                int tDirectoryID = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReaderDirectory["ID"]);
                getCustomerNameQuery(tDirectoryID);
                while (gDataReaderDirectory.Read())
                {
                    String tCustomerName = gDataReaderDirectory["nodeName"].ToString();
                    TreeNode tCustomerNode = directoryNode.Nodes.Add(tCustomerName);
                    tCustomerNode.ExpandAll();
                    directoryNode.ExpandAll();
                    getCustomerIDQuery(tCustomerName);
                    while (gDataReaderCustomer.Read())
                    {
                        int tCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(gDataReaderCustomer["ID"]);
                        getDeviceNameQuery(tCustomerID);
                        while (gDataReaderDevice.Read())
                        {
                            String tDeviceName = gDataReaderDevice["nodeName"].ToString();
                            TreeNode tDeviceNode = tCustomerNode.Nodes.Add(tDeviceName);
                            tDeviceNode.ExpandAll();
                            tCustomerNode.ExpandAll();
                            directoryNode.ExpandAll();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    gConnection.Close();
    }

    public void refreshDatabaseConnection()
    {
        gConnection.Dispose();
        gConnection.Close();
        gConnection = new SQLiteConnection(gDatabaseName);
        gConnection.Open();
    }

    public void getDirectoryNameQuery()
    {
        int tRootID = SQLiteGetRootID();
        gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT nodeName from tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeSubID='{0}'", tRootID));
        gDataReaderRoot = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void getDirectoryIDQuery(String pDirectoryName)
    {
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT ID from tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeName='{0}'", pDirectoryName));
        gDataReaderDirectory = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void getCustomerNameQuery(int pDirectoryID)
    {
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT nodeName from tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeSubID='{0}'", pDirectoryID));
        gDataReaderDirectory = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void getCustomerIDQuery(String pCustomerName)
    {
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT ID from tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeName='{0}'", pCustomerName));
        gDataReaderCustomer = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void getDeviceNameQuery(int pCustomerID)
    {
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("SELECT nodeName from tblNodes where isVisible=1 AND nodeSubID='{0}'", pCustomerID));
        gDataReaderDevice = gCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's no way to insert Simultaneously in a SQLite database. you have to wait until it's done

Comment: how can i wait until it's done , also how can i know when it is done or not ?

Comment: Maybe [Multi-threaded Access to an SQLite3 Database](https://dev.yorhel.nl/doc/sqlaccess) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use locking mechanishm in your helper class and before executing command you can lock and do insert or update. This lock will not allow other threads to enter in to this step for insertion or deletion.
Declare lock object in your helper

```
public static object LockObject = new object();
```

Lock before insertion/update

```
if (tSelectedNodeType == 0)
  {
          gCommand = gConnection.CreateCommand();
          lock(LockObject)
          {
              this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO tblNodes    (nodeName,nodeType,nodeSubID,isVisible) VALUES ('{0}',1,'{1}',1)", pCustomerName, tSelectedID));
        }
  }
```